# undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two questions about undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words'

In my view I am attempting this, and get undefined method:

```
<td><%= distance_of_time_in_words (patient_course_step.started, patient_course_step.completed) %></td>
```

I really want to use this in my model to create a "helper method" for my model.

Examples of helper methods in model:

```
def duration
   distance_of_time_in_words (self.started, self.completed)
end

def status
    if started.nil?
      created_at_formated = created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %l:%M %p")
      return "Not started assigned on #{created_at_formated}"
    elsif !completed.nil?
      completed_formated = completed.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %l:%M %p")
      return "Completed at #{completed_formated}"
    else
      last_viewed_formated = last_viewed.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %l:%M %p")
      return "In Progress, last viewed at #{last_viewed_formated}"
    end
  end
```

1. How can I get distance_of_time_in_words to work in my view
2. Is it a good practice to have helper methods in a model (as shown above)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not good practice to do this, but I understand the need for it. See [this snippet on DZone](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7489) on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that should solve my model problem, but why doesn't the helper work from the view? Do I need to include it somewhere in a configuration file?

Comment: I got it working from my model, but it doesn't work from my view. I don't really need it to work from there, but it is interesting that it doesn't work

Comment: How is it not working? Calling a Helper in the model, calling that in the View? What's it saying?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `your_object_name.distance`. It should work